# Go - Syscall to close serial port hangs after reboot (Linux)

Tags: linux, go, usb

I have an application that opens a serial connection to a device and only reads data from said device. No data is written. This service starts at boot time and should only stop at restart/shutdown. When the service stops, the syscall to close the serial port will sit for at least 30 seconds before completing. Starting and stopping the service in the same session will be immediate. The hang only occurs during the first run of the application since boot.

**donglereader.go**

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/tarm/serial"
)

type Dongle struct {
    serialPort    *serial.Port
    devicePresent bool
    State
}

func NewDongle(dongleName string) (d *Dongle, err error) {

    d = &Dongle{devicePresent: false}

    config := &serial.Config{
        Name:        dongleName,
        ReadTimeout: time.Duration(300 * time.Millisecond),
        Baud:        115200}
    sport, err := serial.OpenPort(config)
    if err != nil {
        return d, err
    }
    d.serialPort = sport
    d.devicePresent = true
    return d, nil
}

func (dongle *Dongle) Close() {
    if dongle.serialPort != nil {
        dongle.serialPort.Close()
    }
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

func main() {
   dongle, err := NewDongle("dongle name")
   if err != nil {
       // handle error
   }

   go readDongle(dongle) // forever (or until program is stopped)

   // listen for shutdown. code beyond this point will be executed when the program has been asked to stop. perform graceful shutdown

   dongle.Close()
}
```

This all works well, but if this is the first time running since the last boot up, it will hang at this line in: **zsyscall_linux.go** when the `dongle.serialPort.Close()` is called
`_, _, e1 := Syscall(SYS_CLOSE, uintptr(fd), 0, 0)`

Eventually it will finish, but the idea is to minimize downtime during a reboot, and 30+ seconds of hanging doesn't help. Why is there a difference in downtime if the connection has been opened and closed already before? Are there any ways to force close the communication channel? What is the harm in bypassing the close altogether?

What I tried:
Removing dongle.Close(). This resolves the issue, but doesn't perform a full graceful shutdown.
Utilizing other Serial libraries. No change.
Adding several minutes of delay in start time at boot. No change.

**Edit 1**
Doing more troubleshooting led to a little clearer picture. I discovered that bringing the system up from a cold boot does NOT have this issue. This only happens after a warm reboot. With this, I stopped my service, unloaded the driver associated with serial devices (cdc_acm), reloaded the driver, start/stopped my service, and encountered the hang again. Therefore, I've deduced that the process of unloading the driver is what initiates this issue. But why? Furthermore, I wrote up a basic Python script to connect to the device, poll once for data, and close the connection. Same exact issue. What's interesting is that the file descriptor closes immediately even when the hang occurs. No errors are returned. Stepping through the assembly code in Go led me to this:

**asm_linux_amd64.s**

```
TEXT ·Syscall(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-56
CALL runtime·entersyscall(SB)
MOVQ a1+8(FP), DI
MOVQ a2+16(FP), SI
MOVQ a3+24(FP), DX
MOVQ trap+0(FP), AX // syscall entry
SYSCALL    <-- debug hangs here
// rest of call
```

Considering that the connection closes immediately, regardless of whether or not it hangs, I suppose I could add a manual timeout to kill the process if the graceful shutdown exceeds X amount of seconds. But I'd still like to know why this syscall hangs. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can not fully reproduce your problem. But I see two things in your code that might be the cause.

- Your code is racy, dongle is shared between go routines without any synchronization. Adding the `-race` flag to `go build` will detect these problems. With a race, all bets are off.
- Close is called without logging the error. Since close is giving you trouble, it might be returning an error that helps you debug your problem.

Comment: Didn't detect any issues with the -race flag. I also didn't see any errors returned from Close()

It appears the close is completing correctly, but takes longer than anticipated. I'm wondering if it could be a firmware issue in the device I'm connecting to.

Comment: @idontcare It could. I remember seeing a similar issue a few years ago. I ended up forcing the process to exist if close blocks for a few seconds as a workaround.